# How to install a user-specific instance of Perl?

Tags: macos, perl

My background is Windows-centric, and I can't figure out how to install my own "user copy" of `perl` to which I can add modules, etc.  OS X already has its own "system perl".

Comment: Mac OS X already has Perl installed. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: cool, something to get rid of those "you haven't voted on questions in a while" popups!

Comment: (just kidding; this is actually a good question once the non-question parts that make it sound like spam mail are removed.)

Comment: Voting to re-open now that it's been edited.

Answer (score 5):

I use [`perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlbrew) to install my own instance of Perl. `cpan Module::Name` will install the modules.

XCode with the optional Commandline Tools package must be installed first to provide the necessary tools to build `perl`. (Thansk friedo!)

Comment: Open an terminal, execute: 

    "curl -kL http://install.perlbrew.pl | bash"

close the terminal and open another one.

    "perlbrew install perl-5.16.0"
    "perlbrew switch perl-5.16.0"


and you're done.

To check, which perl you are using, type
 
    "which perl"

into your terminal. You should see something like

    $ /home/fanlim/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.xxx

and everything is ok.

Too install modules, just install cpanm via perlbrew

    "perlbrew install-cpanm" 


then you can install your Modules without root just with cpanm like
    "cpanm Catalyst::Devel"

Comment: Does anyone know if he needs to install a compiler. I've never used OS X.

Comment: Yes. XCode with the optional Commandline Tools package must be installed first.

Comment: @friedo: that's correct. I forgot this in my previous post, because I installed XCode to use it with MacPorts.